# In a cap or wearing a cap?

Tags: grammar, phrases

What's the correct construction:

> Middle-aged man **in** a baseball cap and a blazer

or

> Middle-aged man **wearing** a baseball cap and a blazer

Comment: Purely subjectively, they both seem fine.

Comment: Both are understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preposition ***[in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in)*** is often used with the idiomatic meaning of:

> - ***wearing:***
>
>   - *Do you recognize that man in the grey suit?
>       Pat can't resist men in uniform.
>       You look nice in green (= green clothes).*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

As you can see from [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20a%20baseball%20cap%2Cwearing%20a%20baseball%20cap&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20baseball%20cap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwearing%20a%20baseball%20cap%3B%2Cc0) both expressions "in a baseball hat" and "wearing a baseball hat" are commonly used.

Answer (score -1):

> Middle-aged man in a baseball cap and a blazer
>
> OR
>
> Middle-aged man wearing a baseball cap and a blazer

Both are fine. "... in a baseball cap ... ", "... in a blazer  ...", "... in jeans and a teeshirt ..." are all proper uses of **in**. It has an idiomatic aspect. **Wearing** is more precise.

From Merriam-Webster:

> [**in**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in): used as a
>   function word to indicate inclusion, location, or position within
>   limits; *in the lake*, *wounded in the leg*, *in the summer*